# Power Queries in Excel just default to "anonymous" and doesn't ask for login info

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, sharepoint, power-query

I have created multiple Excel sheets for my coworkers, many of which involve power query connections to our corporate SharePoint site. When I set it up, I logged into my SharePoint account to authenticate.

The reports refresh for me easily. However, when I send the file to somebody else, and they try to refresh it, they get an "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Mashup.Engine.INterface.ResourceAccessForbiddenException' was thrown" error. They can resolve it by going into power query, data source settings, edit permissions, then choosing "organizational account" instead of "anonymous". once they do that, it works forever.

THe problem is, I have a lot of users. Is there a way to make my queries in such a way that it prompts them to login rather than just throwing an exception? I want them to be able to refresh the reports without having to go into power query, which many of them cannot do without support.

I'm **not** looking for it to save the password in the file or anything like that - users definitely need to login with their own account, I just want it to remember to use "organizational" authentication instead of "anonymous" by default.

The issue seems to be the same as the one referenced here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5ea5742-db99-4507-9844-e4a3a36c67df/excel-power-query-anonymous-credentials?forum=powerquery (where no solution is provided).

Comment: [This MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-data-source-settings-and-permissions-power-query-9f24a631-f7eb-4729-88dd-6a4921380ca9) under "Manage data source credentials" would suggest you'd have to either edit the global permissions or to Clear the permissions. This might have to be done ONCE for each user. (I can't check this through my system)

Comment: Does this help: [Share external data by using an ODC file (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-external-data-by-using-an-odc-file-power-query-d969f7d7-28a7-4593-8dec-be49e4c96e5c)?

Comment: @1NN If I follow that process, I think it saves the users 1 click (getting to data source settings without going into the power query window). I suppose that's an improvement, but not quite what I was hoping for.

Comment: @harrymc if I create the connection using an ODC file, will it not introduce credentials problems as well?

Comment: The [ODC file format](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-ODCFF/%5BMS-ODCFF%5D.pdf) includes connection string which can include username and passwords, although these strings are often stored in plaintext. I don't know if that is acceptable, and I can't test this either.

Comment: Not acceptable as mentioned in the question already. Users need to use their own credentials, not stored in the file.

Comment: What is your data source? SharePoint?

Comment: Yes. SharePoint lists

Comment: Can you set the sharepoint file to be shared to read-only/"anyone with the link" so that no authentication is needed?

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried renaming the .xlsx file to .zip and extracting to a folder. Search through all the files esp. .xml files and see if you can "pre-blank"/"set to organisational" the credentials somehow. You could even try and compare the file contents of the .xlsx file before and after the "set to organisational" was done from within Excel to try and pin point where inside .xlsx zip file this setting is stored.

Comment: Can't turn off authorization no.

Comment: I'll try the XLSX zip rename and see if I can find anything.

Comment: I found no relveant keywords in the zip file @Mobus.

Answer (score 1):

There have been hundreds of posts published on the subject,
in addition to the one you found.
No real solution was ever found, except that of *the end-user*
clearing the permissions from the source, perhaps time and again.
This problem is only related to using OneDrive or SharePoint as sources.
Even VBA cannot delete these credentials.

Some "solutions" are listed in the YouTube video
[How to use Power Query to connect to a file on OneDrive or SharePoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igcCbKqtwrk),
but each one is more complicated than the previous, so are totally unsuitable
for end-users.

I have done some research, but ended up with only these two solutions that I see
as viable:

- The solution you already found of clearing the permissions.
- Export the data to a network share, perhaps in `.csv` format,
  and give all users access to it.

The second solution avoids the headache of credentials, but lacks the
technological sophistication of the first one.

Comment: Can you not perhaps mandate that everyone must use the onedrive client and sync to their pc. That way Excel only needs to access a local file and authentication is handle by the onedrive client?

Comment: @Mobus: The problem would be publishing the query, as it would pertain only to the computer where it originated. In any case, the poster uses SharePoint.

Comment: My users are not on the same corporate network as each other. The SharePoint site is in the cloud and not securing the data is not an option.

Comment: Are you on Azure?

Comment: If you are, see [Web connector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/web/web).

Comment: I don't use power query often and didn't even know you can publish it. How does the publishing work? As a curiosity, can you explain a little how your setup is working, what type of data are you handling, how and why does it go from sharepoint list to excel/power query and back to whom, in what format?

Comment: @Mobus: Questions to the poster belong on the post itself, not on my answer.

Comment: @harrymc I was unsure where to comment. My first comment was additional to your suggestion of a csv file on network storage. Both our suggestions in this context aren't suitable because the OP requires the publishing feature.  But it makes sense that this new requirement be updated/answered in the question. Greg, please respond by editing you original question

Comment: @harrymc yes on Azure

Comment: @harrymc can't get the web connector to work for this list

Comment: The video linked is not helpful for my situation at all. On top of being not meant for end-users as you mentioned, it's also primarily around accessing files on sharepoint, whereas my data is in sharepoint lists.